# Make a circle follow the mouse

Tags: java

I am trying to create an infinite loop in which there are circles. Wherever the mouse moves, the circles will create a line and follow. I have created an infinite loop, but I cannot get the circles to follow the mouse. I am supposed to use `mouseX()` and `mouseY()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StdDraw.setScale(0,100); // initialize StdDraw, set scale to 0-100

    Double xCoor = 50.0; // set the xCoor(dinate) to 50
    Double yCoor = 50.0; // set the yCoor(dinate) to 50

    //StdDraw.filledCircle(50, 50, 10); // draw a filled circle in the middle of the screen.

    while(true) //infinite loop
    {
        int R = (int)(Math.random()*256); // R random color for Red component
        int G = (int)(Math.random()*256); // G random color for Green component
        int B = (int)(Math.random()*256); // B random color for Blue component

        StdDraw.show(1); // show the circles at a slower pace
        StdDraw.setPenColor(R, G, B); // set the pen color to all 3 components random
        StdDraw.filledCircle(50, 50, 10); // draw a filled circle in the center of the screen
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: So what is the result that you are getting? Is it remaining static? `StdDraw.filledCircle(mouseX(),mouseY(), 10); ` should do the job?

Comment: that's what i thought, but the circle doesn't move, it just flashes with random colors. I am also confused on how to initialize 'mouseX()' and 'mouseY()'

Comment: you need to implement the `MouseListener` interface first to get the location of the mouse on a component.